# Physical strength of replicants

Tags: science-based, biology, science-fiction

The concept appears often in literature: A human(-like) being which is physically more capable than normal humans. However since humans are easier to relate to than anything else he is not a robot, a cyborg or magically enhanced. (Also no steel-bones or similar.) I stick to replicants, since the depiction of blade runner seems to be close to what I have in mind. However I'm not interested in how they are depicted in the films/books but what we can realistically expect.

I'm wondering how much more capable a replicant than a human can be. I'm asking for the strength but if you happen to know something on endurance, speed, etc. I'm fine with that, too.

EDIT: With being human I mean when looking an them you can't tell the difference and they have the same organs etc. A normal doctor might not be able to tell the difference unless he makes physical tests.

Comment: You should remove the fist sentence and just ask how we can improve the human by through genetic engineering. it is a much narrower answer and less likely to be closed. You should also specify how much they have to pass for human becasue that also has a big effect.

Comment: Okey, you're right, I asked it in a very bad way. I think it would be better to close it and rewrite the whole question. However, I just realised that I cannot delete it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if there's anything to this idea, but I'm of the opinion that with our big, self-aware brains, we might have some kind of "circuit" that actually *limits* our physical strength. Basically it's the **don't do that shit cos it's gonna hurt like hell afterward!** circuit. It's a matter of self preservation vs actual potential of existing muscle mass.

Depending on what kind of "replicant" you're positing, such a being could be apparently much stronger than a human because it's got no awareness of self and no **don't do that shit cos it's gonna hurt like hell afterward!** circuit. I've read for example that adult chimps, which compared to humans are relatively small, are terribly strong. A replicant might be comparable.

On the other hand, if your "replicant" has that circuit and the self awareness and the ability to act on it, it might end up every bit as ordinary as an ordinary human.

[3 Scientific Facts That Prove That Muscular Limits Is Purely Psychological.](http://scientificbrains.com/3-scientific-facts-that-prove-that-muscular-limits-is-purely-psychological/)

[Hysterical Strength](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hysterical_strength)

Comment: keep in mind there are humans born without the ability to feel pain, and they tend to hurt themselves a lot, your replicants will have the same problem, they will be constantly overtaxing their bodies.

Answer (score 2):

We humans are unusually weak compared to our genetic cousins.  Orangutans are believed to be [seven times](http://bioweb.uwlax.edu/bio203/s2008/ahrens_just/interesting%20facts.htm) as strong as humans and share [97%](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-1350807/How-humans-97-orangutans-New-research-shows-DNA-matches.html) of our DNA.

With a little genetic tinkering, military scientists will someday close that gap by a fraction of a percent, producing a hybrid with tremendous strength, natural climbing abilities and beautiful auburn hair.

[Scrap the caddy, Clyde!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BkD7UTYrbB0)

Comment: Not only orangs, but also chimps are physically much stronger than us; and chimps are very very close to us, biologically speaking. The difference seems to be that we are adapted for long distance running; that was our ecological niche before we became fully human and shed the need to _have_ an ecological niche. Sometime a long time ago we discarded almost all muscle mass which could not be sustained long-term in aerobic mode, whereas the other great apes kept a lot of muscle mass which is only available for short spurts of effort. +1 for bringing the other great apes into focus.

Comment: @AlexP, Thanks for the edits!  I considered chimps for my answer, but didn't know of a good video to link.  Also, the naming of a orang-human hybrid is easier...  ChimpMANzee is a bit of a tongue-twister, where as OrangoMan (or Orange Man for short) sounds better to me.  If I introduce a soldier to the reader as an orange man, and then mention his hair color, the reader might still be surprised when I later demonstrate and explain the soldier's strength and climbing ability.  Makes a nice "oh wow!" moment easy.